# Verify Android Bitmap is GrayScale

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, grayscale

I got a doubt. When I obtain the pixels from a `Bitmap` in Android. I've got an image loaded inside it, this image is a grayscale image. If I make a `getPixels()` and check the values I can see values with R != G != B.

I think I can check if it's grayscale if the values of the three slides (R, G and B) got the same value, but I couldn't be possible. 
There is a way to verify it?

Lots of thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let first off say that there are a couple of ways of accomplishing this.

I would say get the size of the image using (something like)

```
int myHeight = myImage.getHeight();
int myWidth  = myImage.getWidth();
```

I would say in this case you may also want to verify the Bitmap' config as it could be one of 3 different formats

```
ALPHA_8, ARGB_8888, or RGB_565
```

You get the configuration using the

```
myImage.getConfig()
```

routine.  We will get back to how this should be used later.

Now that you know the size of the image you should run a dual loop structure as follows:

```
boolean isGrayscaleImage = true;  // assume it is grayscale until proven otherwise

for(int i = 0; i < myWidth; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < myHeight; j++){
        int currPixel = myImage.getPixel(i, j);

        if( false == isGrayScalePixel(currPixel) ){
            isGrayscaleImage = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Back to HOW TO TEST IF THE PIXEL IS GRAYSCALE:
If the image is stored as ALPHA_8 it really isn't a grayscale image, but it could technically be converted to one by turning the image into an ARGB_8888 image and setting the Alpha value to 0xFF and each of the R, G, and B components to the alpha value provided within the original 8 bit ALPHA_8 based image.

If the image is RGB_565 formatted, this is a bit trickier as you will have to pull apart the R, G, and B values into their own bytes by yourself using shift and MASKING operators.  Once you have done this, it is essentially like processing the ARGB_8888 image (talked about below).

For the ARGB_8888 image:
the alpha channel SHOULD always be 0xFF.

As you stated in your question a pixel is considered grayscale if R == G == B
SO (Sample Code Might Look As Follows)

```
boolean isGrayScalePixel(int pixel){
    int alpha = (pixel && 0xFF000000) >> 24;
    int red   = (pixel && 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
    int green = (pixel && 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    int blue  = (pixel && 0x000000FF);

    if( 0 == alpha && red == green && green == blue ) return true;
    else return false;

}
```

There are optimizations that could be made, but I am trying to document the main algorithm for you.

Hope this helps you out :-)

Comment: That's what i've done but the pixels in an grayscale image got different values and I think, as you, that they should got the same. That's my problem.

Comment: Well.........  This is how you verify, which is what your question was.  Do you have the actual image, have you opened it in an imaging application and zoomed in to see if there is indeed colors that are not grayscale???

Comment: I apply the verify as a pre-processing step of the image right after load it, without zooming or other different operations. If this image is opened with Matlab I found it as an image with only one layer and it's a grayscale image (not an indexed color image) with pixels in levels from 0 to 255.

Comment: Have you done the checking to see if it is ARGB_8888 or ARGB_565?  When you say that R != G != B, how far off are the values?

Comment: Found the problem. That was that all the images are loaded as ARGB_565 and the scales of values are not the same for R or B than for G. The solution was to force the `decodeFile()` function with `options.preferredConfig` parameter set to `ARGB_8888`. Then everyone can get the correct values with the same scales.

Comment: Great to hear, At least I was able to help you get on the path :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note the use of && (boolean AND) when masking should be a single & (bitwise AND) as below:

```
int alpha = (pixel & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
int red   = (pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
int green = (pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
int blue  = (pixel & 0x000000FF);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you have to do is check whether the R,G and B values are the same then just do it using `Colors.red()`, `Colors.green()` or `Colors.blue()`.

Here is a small portion of the actual code.

```
for(int x=0;x< bmp.getWidth();x++) {
    for(int y=0;y< bmp.getHeight();y++) {    

        int pixel=bmp.getPixel(x,y);
        int alpha=Color.alpha(pixel);            
        int gray_color=Color.red(pixel);         
        int gray_color1=Color.green(pixel);

        //int gray_color=pixel&0x000000ff;
        //int gray_color1=(pixel&0x0000ff00)>>8;
        //int gray_color2=(pixel&0x00ff0000)>>16;
        //int gray_color3=Math.abs((pixel&0xff000000))>>24;

        int pixels= (int)Math.pow(gray_color,gamma);
        k.add(""+alpha+" "+gray_color+" "+gray_color1);
        bmp.setPixel(x,y,Color.argb(alpha,pixels,pixels,pixels));
    }
}
```

You can see I have commented the shifting and masking part.