# How to know if image is in grayscale?

Tags: android

When I was used BufferedImage I can determine what type of image using getColorModel and using getType, but how can I do that on a Bitmap?

I've already tried this once and the boolean always return true;

```
public boolean isGreyscale(Bitmap image)
{
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int pixel,red, green, blue;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            pixel = image.getPixel(i, j);
            red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
            if (red != green || green != blue ) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And I tried using OpenCV and didn't know what to do so I kind of check the channel and always return 4 channel including the alpha,

```
 public boolean checkIfGrayscale(Bitmap bitmap){
    Mat matImages = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, matImages);
    matImages.channels();

    if(matImages.channels()>1){
        return  false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Because I thought on OpenCV grayscale image is 1 channel, and rgb is 4 channel

And nothing works. When I tried to input rgb the return still true. I have been stuck for a week .

Comment: Library request are off-topic here. You can ask on [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Comment: then i edit it that i like to solve it using android studio

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957348/verify-android-bitmap-is-grayscale

Comment: I had done it but still can't solve it @ivan